# What does ~頂ければと思います mean? Why does such a construction happen?

Tags: translation, ellipsis

I've heard phrases sometimes like:

> チェックいただければと思います。*chekku itadakereba to
>   omoimasu*

"If you check this ... I think."?
Why is that ~と思います at then end of the phrase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

> チェックしていただければと思います。 chekku shite itadakereba to omoimasu

and it means "It will be great if you could check (this (for me))"

also there is other similar usages with straight forward meaning.

> 〜していただける**と幸いです**。 ~ shite itadakeru to saiwai desu.
>
> (If you could do this, I will be very good luck) <- not sure this is correct English though.
>
> 〜していただける**とありがたいです**。 ~ shite itadakeruto arigatai desu.
>
> (If you could do this, I will be very thankful / appreciated)

Comment: Essentially 「〜て頂ければと思います」 is just one of the longer phrases here or something similar, except that the middle part has been left out. Leaving out parts of sentences is common.

Comment: is this sentence structure a form of keigo?

Comment: Without the して (as in the original post), it sounds like he's asking for the check at a restaurant, not asking them to check something.  "It'd be great if I could get the check now."  Just pointing that out.

Comment: @Mark: Yes, all examples here means “please do ～,” but more polite than saying, say, チェックしてください.

Answer (score 10):

This is an aside, but here is some personal thoughts about チェックいただければ vs チェックしていただければ.

チェックしていただければ is undoubtedly correct, and I personally consider チェックいただければ as incorrect.  However, I imagine that some (native) speakers use チェックいただければ in an attempt to make the expression more polite than チェックしていただければ.

In general, a more polite expression for ～していただければ is ご～いただければ.  For example, チェックする and [確認]{かくにん}する is almost synonymous, and both 確認していただければと思います and ご確認いただければと思います mean “It will be great if you could check it,” the latter being more polite.

Now a problem arises when the word before して is a loanword because attaching the prefix ご to a loanword is usually unacceptable.  チェックしていただければ would become ごチェックいただければ, but this form sounds wrong.  Therefore one compromise may be to drop ご and say チェックいただければ.